# Swift protocol conformance when returning a generic

Tags: swift, function, generics, protocols

Here's an example:

```
protocol Feed {
    func items<T>() -> [T]? where T: FeedItem
}

protocol FeedItem {}

class FeedModel: Feed, Decodable {
    func items<T>() -> [T]? where T : FeedItem {
        return [FeedItemModel]() // Error: Cannot convert return expression of type '[FeedItemModel]' to return type '[T]?'
    }
}

class FeedItemModel: FeedItem, Decodable {}
```

Why does it:

A) try to convert to `T` when `T` is a generic, not a type?
B) does not recognize `FeedItemModel` as conforming to `FeedItem`?

Comment: Unerlated, but it's almost never the right approach to have an optional array - just use an empty array if there are no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A)

`T` **is** a type, a homogenous concrete type specified at runtime.
Imaging `T` is `class Foo : FeedItem` it's obvious that `FeedItemModel` cannot be converted to `Foo`

B)

`FeedItemModel` is recognized as conforming to `FeedItem` but this is irrelevant.

---

It's often a mix-up of generics and protocols. Generic types are not covariant. If you need covariant types use an associated type.

Comment: "type specified at runtime"? I think compile-time

Comment: No, it's specified at runtime. At compile time it's *some* type conforming to the given constraints.

Answer (score 2):

```
func items<T>() -> [T]? where T : FeedItem
```

This says that the caller can define `T` to be whatever they want, as long as `T` conforms to FeedItemModel, and this function will return an optional array of those.

FeedItemModel is *something* that conforms to FeedItem, but it is not promised to be the type `T` that the caller requested.

As an example, consider:

```
class OtherModel: FeedItem {}
```

According to your function signature, I can do this:

```
let ms: [OtherModel]? = FeedModel().items()
```

But your function won't then return `[OtherModel]?` to me. I suspect you don't actually mean this to be generic. I expect you mean:

```
func items() -> [FeedItemModel]?
```

or possibly

```
func items() -> [FeedItem]?
```

(Though I would think very hard before doing the latter one and make sure that the protocol existential is really doing useful work here.)

Answer (score 1):

Either you can ignore generics because because it only applies to that one function and it isn't needed since directly saying that the return type is `[FeedItem]?` yields the same result

```
protocol Feed {
    func items() -> [FeedItem]?
}

class FeedModel: Feed, Decodable {
    func items() -> [FeedItem]?  {
        return [OtherModel]()
    }
}
```

If you on the other hand want a generic protocol then you should use a associated type

```
protocol Feed2 {
    associatedtype T: FeedItem

    func items() -> [T]?
}

class FeedModel2: Feed2, Decodable {
    typealias T = FeedItemModel
    func items() -> [T]?  {
        return [FeedItemModel]()
    }
}
```